# Subquery is not supported on 'IsDeleted' of type 'Entities.Product'

Tags: linq-to-sql, exception

I'm using Linq to SQL and trying to filter data using DataOptions and AssociateWith.
I have a table called Products that has a primary key called Id and a flag called IsDeleted with sql-datatype bit.

When I use the following code I get **"Subquery is not supported on 'IsDeleted' of type 'Entities.Product'"** exception on AssociateWith method.

```
var context = new DataContext();
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.AssociateWith<Product>(p => !p.IsDeleted);
context.LoadOptions = options;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this as I have the exact same problem

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but might help someone. When I was doing eager loading, by mistake I put `AssociateWith` in my code instead of `LoadWith` and ended up with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are only allowed two filter on a subquery of a one->many relationship and can only use a specific set of expressions, detailed here:
Where
OrderBy
ThenBy
OrderByDescending
ThenByDescending
Take

(more info here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534221.aspx)

Comment: Why is what you have said a specific problem for @Mohammadreza ?